# PHP - creating multiple forms

Tags: php, forms

I would like to create a dialog where I am asking the user about his language skills.
the construction looks as follow:

- form
- input
- select language input
- select years of experiance
- button(add new language) {or} button(submit)
- /form

the problem I have is that I only can pass my values to my db after I have collected all information.

I could work with static forms and but I hope that there is an easier way which I did not figured out yet. I had a look into working with the loop function but I am running here in problems as well.

Comment: Please clarify the issue. You are looking to have multiple select/text boxes for each language?

Comment: I would like to reuse the same form for each language and the form will contain 3 or 4 check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Give each input a different name. You can use one form, one submission.

e.g. language1, language2, language1_years, language2_years

```
<select size="1" name="language1">
    <option value="english">english</option>
    <option value="spanish">spanish</option>
</select>

Number of Years:<input type="text" name="language1" />

<select size="1" name="language2">
    <option value="english">english</option>
    <option value="spanish">spanish</option>
</select>

Number of Years:<input type="text" name="language2" />
```

You can also add the button: Add more languages.. with a little JavaScript/Ajax.